# sharepoint webpart not loading for some users?

Tags: sharepoint

I am supporting a SharePoint 2010 site.Apart from this application few users unable to view the the web-part content.the web part not loading correctly & showing an error message.

Please help me....

thanks in advance.
sreenath E

Comment: Can you please edit your post and add the error message that the users are receiving?

Comment: below the error code: This webpart can not be displayed. You can try to solve this bij opening this page in a sharepoint compatible html-editor as microsoft sharepoint designer. please contact the webserver support department if this problem still exists

Comment: What does this particular webpart do?  Is this a view into a list or library?

Comment: @KevinMills :The problem resolved now by resetting the internet setting .....:v ..... Any way thanks for your help....

Comment: @Kevin Mills : I need a help for one requirement, if you know please help me..... Am using share point designer for sending an email in my application, but i got one requirement that after sending the email to that particular person the details of the email will record in to some other list,like(email from , to address, send time, subject etc). Is it possible? please help me .... thanks in advance

Comment: Yes this is possible.  However, this is an entirely separate question from the one above.  Please post this as a new question, and I will answer your question there.

Comment: @KevinMills :Already shared the question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158483/how-to-get-the-share-point-designer-email-workflow-log-details-in-a-list