# How to get the share point designer email workflow log details in a list?

Tags: sharepoint-workflow

In my application share point designer is using to send emails.What i want to know that, after sending the email to the receiver the email details like From & to address, email sending time , subject of mail will recorded & need to save in to other list.
Is it possible? please help me to solve the requirement or share me the steps.

Thanks in advance..
Sreenath E

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a variable for each of the items that you need to record in the list. You can populate each variable with the required email info, and use these variables to send your email. Upon completion, add each of the values from the variables to the appropriate column in your list.